# Prevent integer underflow/overflow when receiving integer over TCP

Tags: c, security, tcp, integer-overflow

Say for instance I have a TCP server that needs to know the unsigned integer (`uint32_t`) size of some arbitrary data before receiving said data. In order to receive the arbitrary data the client would first have to send a the size bytes of a `uint32_t` unsigned integer encoded using `htonl` e.g. (client side):

```
uint32_t size_int = // some size integer calculated before
uint32_t nbo_data = htonl(size_int);
// send nbo_data to server...
```

To decode the bytes the server would do the following:

```
// First receive nbo_bytes into receive_buffer...
uint32_t nbo_data;
memcpy(&nbo_data, receive_buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));


uint32_t size_int = ntohl(nbo_data);
```

Now say for instance an attacker sent uint32_t bytes encoded with `htonl` that exceeded the `UINT32_MAX` value/4294967295. How could I prevent an integer overflow/underflow from occurring? Would a simple cast to a larger datatype i.e. `long long` and bounds check be enough? Like so:

```
char receive_buffer[1024];
// First receive nbo_bytes into receive_buffer...
uint32_t nbo_data;
memcpy(&nbo_data, receive_buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));


long long size_int = (long long)ntohl(nbo_data);
// Check if size_int > UINT32_MAX or size_int < 0 here
// If true raise error.
```

Or is there a better approach/is this approach flawed and ineffective?

Comment: It is not possible for a 32 bit quantity to exceed UINT32_MAX.

Comment: @Mat So in other words casting as `long long` and checking bounds/range is redundant?

Comment: Not only is it redundant, it is error-prone too. (And doesn't make sense to start with.)

Comment: Unsigned integers never overflow, they just wrap around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now say for instance an attacker sent uint32_t bytes encoded with
> `htonl` that exceeded the `UINT32_MAX` value/4294967295.

As has been expressed in comments, that's impossible.

`htonl()` just transforms one four-byte sequence into another, such that the resulting sequence is a big-endian (network order) representation of the value of the argument.  If the host machine uses big-endian order natively then that is a no-op.

`uint32_t` expresses an unsigned integer type with 32 value bits and no padding bits.  The interpretation of such a value is mandated by the language specifications, and it leaves no room for a 32-bit pattern that is not interpretable as a `uint32_t`.  The value of `UINT32_MAX` follows from that.

Not even by maliciously twiddling bits can an adversary send a 32-bit value that is not interpretable as a `uint32_t` between 0 and `UINT32_MAX`, inclusive.  Nor will the `uint32_t` received induce `ntohl()` to try to return an out-of-range value, because, again, no out-of-range or invalid values are expressible for type `uint32_t`.

> How could I
> prevent an integer overflow/underflow from occurring?

You don't need to do anything to avoid that.  You should instead focus on how to detect or deal with the possibility that the value received is simply wrong or inconsistent.